# blender symmetries are weird. It works strangely

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]

When I made the chest, I mirror the ball on my body and used join.

The symmetries, which worked well in the face, became not the x-axis of object standards as shown in the picture.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your object origin has moved. Try resetting it.

1. Enable "Affect Only Origins option" (see image)
2. Select your object in object mode and hit Alt+G to reset its transfrom
   [image]

Or

1. Shift + C to reset cursor.
2. right click -> set origin -> to cursor